# Cálculo da soma dos elementos de uma matriz

Tags: c, array, funções

Tenho que desenvolver uma função na linguagem C para somar os elementos de uma matriz quadrada de ordem n desde que i < j. Tentei testar a função que fiz, mas dá erro na linha 15, que diz "expected expression before 'int'". Alguém poderia me ajudar, por favor?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int soma_matriz(int n, int mat[n][n]){
    int i = 0, j = 0, soma = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (j = 0; (j < n); j++){
            if (i < j)
                soma = soma + mat[i][j];
        }
    }
    return soma;
}

int main(){
    int mat[3][3] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, a = 3, somatorio = 0;
    somatorio = soma_matriz(int a, int mat[3][3]);
    printf("O valor e %d", somatorio);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem erros de sintaxe aí, por exemplo chamar a função com sintaxe de declaração e tentar passar o tipo como argumento, isso não existe, inclui aí passar o tamanho do *array*, você passa um valor, que pode ser de uma variável, só isso. Também não estava inicializando o *array* da forma correta. melhorei mais algumas coisas.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int soma_matriz(int n, int mat[n][n]) {
    int soma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) if (i < j) soma += mat[i][j];
    return soma;
}

int main() {
    int mat[3][3] = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}};
    printf("O valor e %d", soma_matriz(3, mat));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/yR54xh). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/prroklqb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/MatrixSum.c).

Você precisa entender oque cada parte do texto quer dizer, porque está ali. Sem entender o que está fazendo, só copiando coisas esperando que funciona só acertará por coincidência, e não aprenderá. O objetivo não pode ser fazer o exercício e sim entender o que está acontecendo por isso precisa estudar cada conceito antes de fazer. Eu digo isso porque aqui ajudamos as pessoas aprenderem a programar e não apenas dizemos o que ela errou pontualmente, que não ensina muito.